# Vue.js x-template works well, but cannot be resolved in IDE

Tags: vue.js

I made a simple html file with vue-router.

I use x-template to define component template.

It works well on chrome browser, but I found that IntelliJ IDE show me a red line.

[image]

I cannot understand why IDE can't resolve this and why my code works well on the browser even though the symbol can't be resolved.

Does anyone have an idea? (The code is written below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Router_App</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <nav>
        <router-link to="/top">Top page</router-link>
        <router-link to="/users">User page</router-link>
    </nav>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="user-list">
    <div>User page</div>
</script>

<script>
    let router = new VueRouter({
        routes: [
            {
                path: '/top',
                component: {
                    template: '<div>Top page</div>'
                }
            },
            {
                path: '/users',
                component: {
                    template: '#user-list'
                }
            }
        ]
    })

    let app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        router: router
    }).$mount()

</script>

</body>

</html>
```